# javascript function works as expected in Firefox or Edge in IE mode but not in Edge native mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, microsoft-edge

I have the following code in my .aspx file:

```
               <p style="font-size: medium; vertical-align: middle; clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto); margin-left: 112px;"> iv. Please Enter an Edit Code for ODL Info:
           <%= Html.TextBox("EditCode") %>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Submit Edit Code", "ODLScreenShot", "Home", null, new { id = "Code_Value" })%>
                
                
           
           </p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('#Code_Value').click(function () {
           var codevalue = $('#EditCode').val(); // get the textbox value 
           this.href = this.href + '?EditCode=' + codevalue; // build new url 
           location.href = this.href; // redirect 
           return false; // cancel default redirect 
       });
   });
</script>
```

In Firefox or in Edge with IE mode enabled for the site, the code works as expected, appending ?EditCode=[value in textbox] to the url

In Edge native mode (and reportedly in Chrome) This does not work.  I have tried loading the most recent version of Jquery and JQuery UI but the behavior is the same.

Comment: I edited the code sample to include the actual html elements (and c# references)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. It works well in IE mode and Edge normal mode. Which version of jQuery do you use? Besides, you can open F12 devtools to check if there's any error in console.